# How to load Firebird 2.1.X fbclient.dll on Windows XP wihout installing Microsoft C++ 2005 Redistributable (vcredist_x86.exe)?

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, firebird

Using fbclient.dll in Firebird 2.1.X in fresh install Windows XP that never install with [Microsoft C++ 2005 Redistrubable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=200B2FD9-AE1A-4A14-984D-389C36F85647&displaylang=en) will cause problem.

I wish to deploy my application that contain fbclient.dll and all related Microsoft C++ 2005 redistributable libraries without installing the redistributable libraries.  Can I do that?  I am running the application in limited account.  Install the VC++ redistributable is not an option here.

My application is developed with Delphi using LoadLibrary to load the fbclient.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [possible](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/minimumclient.htm) to just copy the MSVC runtime into your application directory.
However, a standard installer would be better for automatic updates. And the installer will run under an administrator account, so your limited account is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As i remenber (havent code near me), you can use manifest files.
A little hint can be seen here: http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=2248
http://www.destructor.de/firebird/minimumclient.htm.

Relating posts:
[Mixed Mode Library and CRT Dependencies - HELP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230715/mixed-mode-library-and-crt-dependencies-help)
[Visual Studio 2005 security updates and CRT DLL versions in manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265792/visual-studio-2005-security-updates-and-crt-dll-versions-in-manifest)